How to make a key optional in Union Type
I have a type in my TypeScript project
export type Types = "APPLE" | "MANGO" | "BANANA";

Here I want the BANANA to be optional, i.e.,
If I have created a mapping using the keys in Types for example
const MAPPING: { [key in Types]: string } = {
 APPLE: "Here is Apple",
 MANGO: "Here is Mango",
};

This code gives error it's asking to define mapping for each key if I don't do it gives error:
Property 'BANANA' is missing in type '{ APPLE: string; MANGO: string; }' but required in type '{ APPLE: string; MANGO: string; 
 BANANA: string; }'

To avoid these types of errors, I want to make the BANANA optional also I don't want to change the MAPPING itself, it should remain as [key in Types]. I understand that either using Exclude or Types? would work but this requires changes in a lot of files.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

What could you mean by "I don't want to change the MAPPING fn itself, it should remain as [key in Types]"? Obviously something about MAPPING needs to change. What exactly are you willing to change and what are you not willing to change, and why?

Hey @jcalz what i meant is that in my project the "key in Types" is being used in almost 1000+ files I don't want to go to every-single and handle the optional "BANANA", so I wanted a generic solution where the mappings would remain the same i.e "key in Types" but there could be something which I can change on the Types to make this work,
I understand that changing the mappers itself is the best way here but changing and commiting in 1000+ files is a lot and not sure if it's a good practice

With your example here (which isn't a [mre] since .... isn't real code, so I'm making guesses) there is no way to "change" Types to make just BANANA optional. You have no choice but to modify your 1000+ files. Maybe when you do that you can use a named type instead of the same mapped type 1000 times, so that in the future if you need to make such a change you can then make the change in one place. But right now I don't see any alternative, good practice or no.  Anyway, right now I suppose the answer to this question is just "No, this is impossible". Is that what you want to see?

I've updated the question to show the full example so you can get a better idea of the error, but yes do agree with you I don't think there's any other way around this expect changing every single file.
can you explain what you meant by "Maybe when you do that you can use a named type instead of the same mapped type 1000 times, so that in the future if you need to make such a change you can then make the change in one place."

@IshAsh like this, perhaps: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqzgGc4F44BEAggAokAyAogXAD6ECyRAcgOIDyN9BAQi-wQDcAKGFIUcdmBgBLCADsAhgBsAYlACuMmDnwByPs357R41Oq0wGisAB40APjzC4cAN5wA2gGk4M+XCUIADGyhoAJsD2mFgANJLSckpqmtpYDgC6AFzocAC+cABkLu5evv6BIDBQisEw0ShxCbIKKhZpmQD8OWj5osEKWPBMZACSbDntVja2Q1D+AOZO+G4upBSUOQQAEsBQqDI4RGBgysAEsS5MbOxbu-t+ONbyCxAXLob8WypYEHCKcAARoolEoCMI8iJhAN5EM4CMSONWAB9ADqozQ23YAFU0MjPkZJqlpnY5otlu41mQqHc9gcjiczu94SwOLSHod4SDXu9IUA Now you can use FruitMap in your whole codebase, and when if you need to change it, you change it it one file.

@jcalz yes the later part where the [key in Types]: ..., here it can be anything either a string number, etc I mean the example is reproducible enough even if we change the ... to lets say number and don't add the BANANA key it would still return the same error, In most of the files it is [key in Types]: string only but in a few cases it [key in Types]: number or [key in Types]: { text: string; count?: number; }

Okay, well Alex's suggestion above works, because it's generic in the value type. Does that meet your needs? You do have to change it everywhere first, but once you do it, then you can modify it in one place by touching FruitMap.

yup that works thanks a lot for the help jcalz Alex could you post this as the answer I'll mark it as accepted

The type "BANANA" is just a string type. It can't encode any information about how all other types may use that string type. And the mappings that you don't want to change in 1000+ files are where you use this string type, so there is where you would need to change it. There is no getting around that.
However, you can ensure that you don't have this issue again by using a named type which you can import into 1000+ other files. Now you have one place where you can change this logic in the future.
Depending on what you need, here's one way that could look:
type RequiredFruits = 'APPLE' | 'MANGO'
type OptionalFruits = 'BANANA'

export type Fruits = RequiredFruits | OptionalFruits // 'APPLE' | 'MANGO' | 'BANANA'

export type FruitMap<T> =
  { [K in RequiredFruits]: T } &
  { [K in OptionalFruits]?: T }

This splits your keys into two unions, one required and one optional. Then you can intersect two mapped types to get one object type that has the right mix of required and optional fields.
Then it exports FruitMap, which is a mapped type where the value type of that map can be anything you want. But what keys are required are always the same.
Now you can:
import type { FruitMap } from './fruit-map'

const MAPPING: FruitMap<string> = {
 APPLE: "Here is Apple",
 MANGO: "Here is Mango",
 BANANA: "also a banana"
};

const MAPPING_WITHOUT_BANANA: FruitMap<string> = {
 APPLE: "Here is Apple",
 MANGO: "Here is Mango",
};


See playground

You could use an intersection:
Playground
export type Types = "APPLE" | "MANGO" | "BANANA";

type MakeOptional<T extends string, E extends T, V = any> = {
    [K in Exclude<T, E>]: V
} & {
    [K in E]?: V
} extends infer M ? { [K in keyof M]: M[K] } : never

type Mapped = MakeOptional<Types, 'BANANA', string>

const MAPPING: Mapped = {
 APPLE: "Here is Apple",
 MANGO: "Here is Mango",
};


const MAPPING: { [key in Types]?: number } = { APPLE: 1 };


I misread the question, my solution makes "APPLE" and "MANGO" optional too, but only "BANANA" should be. Alex Wayne's solution is the correct one in this case
